# Browsing Android .apk files on windows

Tags: windows, file-management, android

Is there any application or any Windows explorer plugin that can show '.apk' files like when you brows them in android file browsers? I mean showing icon of program, its version, ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[apk-viewer](http://www.wcn.it/apk-viewer.zip) works as a standalone app.

[apkshellext](https://code.google.com/p/apkshellext/) works as a shell extension:

Unfortunately they could not used together, you have to choose one as default program for `.apk`.

Comment: apkshellext  works fine